# html to PDF not rendering properly while using jsPDF

Tags: jspdf, obsidian

I am trying to develop a plugin to export markdown file to PDF.

Here is a sample markdown content:

```
# What is Obsidian ?
Obsidian is a **markdown** editor.
```

I am using `marked` library to convert `markdown => html string` after which using `html` function of `JSPDF` library to convert to PDF and save

The code snippet is as follows:

```
const pdf = new jsPDF()

//converting markDown text to html
const htmlContent = await marked(markedDownContent);

pdf.html(htmlContent, {
callback: (doc) => {
doc.save("output.pdf");
},
x: 0,
y: 0,
margin: 10
});
```

However, the text generated in PDF is poorly formatted as seen below:

[image]

I need help in fixing the styling of the text generated in the PDF document.

**Edit**
As mentioned in the comments, the `html` generated is as follows:

```
<h1>What is Obsidian ?</h1>
<p>Obsidian is a <strong>markdown</strong> editor.</p>
```

Comment: I think debugging the contents of `htmlContent` would be a start.

Comment: @Luuk Here is the htmlContent:
<h1>What is Obsidian ?</h1>
<p>Obsidian is a <strong>markdown</strong> editor.</p>

Comment: Please do a copy/paste of that _HTML_ into this page: https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea, and conclude that this is **not** valid **HTML**, and therefore cannot be converted to something without errors....